# Is there an option in Windows to create a file with bytes contains in RAM?

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems

There is a program (program A), that uses some specific file in some folder. Normally that file is on the hard disk.

I need to write a program (program B) that can create such file, but this file should be physically in RAM, not on HDD. So if you unplug HDD, you could not find the file.

I also have no access to program A code. But I want A to interpreting that file as a normal file.

Is it possible in Windows to do something like that?

Comment: [shared memory?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/creating-named-shared-memory)

Comment: @dewaffled am I able to create a file (with a path like "C:/Temp/file.txt") using shared memory, not changing program A behavior? The case is that I can't modify program A, and make it use some mechanisms like MemoryMappedFiles (it is obfuscated Java, actually). But I can make everything in program B.

Comment: It's near impossible, from user code, to force memory to be allocated in physical memory. Is that *really* what you want? Or are you mistaking "RAM" with (virtual) memory?

Comment: @ken: How many programs had to be rewritten to take advantage of symbolic links?

Comment: @KonstantinRybchynski RAM is normally volatile memory where stored information is lost if power is removed. Are you meaning the ROM? I am wondering what's kind of program you are developing and what's the purpose of the specific file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to have a file that is only in memory is to use a [RAM-drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive). You can find free RAM-drives and probably some open source implementations but they do require a kernel driver. NTFS mount points will allow you to mount this drive as a subfolder on drive C: if that is a requirement.

From a programming point of view, the only thing program B would be able to do is to set the delete-on-close flag after program A has opened the file. Depending on how A uses the file, you might be able to just delete the file, and if not, B would have to call [`SetFileInformationByHandle(FileDispositionInfo, ...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileinformationbyhandle) on the file handle but this will only work if program A opens the file with the share flags set to allow delete. I have never tested this so I'm not 100% sure it would work if power was lost. NTFS does have journaling that makes sure the filesystem state is correct but I'm not sure if it applies to the delete flag.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think that works if the application uses `CreateFile` and friends to deal with files. Very few applications use IShellFolder and ask for IStream when they read files.